How to set monitor's input source without ddcutil?
I have a PC (OS - Ubuntu Server), but I haven't monitor for it, so I decided to connect laptop (OS - Ubuntu) to it via HDMI and change input source of laptop's monitor. I'll reinstall OS on my PC, so I can't simply stream (with programs like teamviewer) image from PC to the monitor. Also laptop's monitor doesn't support DDC/CI, so I can't use ddcutil.
P. S. I viewd post about using male-male VGA, but my computers doesn't support VGA
